# Cancel run in azureml sdk2

Tags: azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I'm using azureml sdk2 and I want to add execution cancel condition to my code but I don't know how to do it?

```
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
ml_client = MLClient(
credential=credential,
subscription_id = "***",
resource_group_name = "***",
workspace_name = "***"
)
```

```
job = command(
    code="./temp-workspace/",  # location of source code
    command="python train_script.py",
    description = description,
    tags=tags,
    environment=myenv,
    compute=cpu_compute_target,
    experiment_name=experiment_name,
    display_name=registered_model_name,
    )
```

```
# submit the command
returned_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(job)
```

how can i cancel this job in local run?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel the job with `ml_client` you can use below code snippet:

```py
ml_client.jobs.begin_cancel(job_details.name)
```

Job started and cancelled with `ml_client` as shown:
[image]

With above code the job was cancelled as per requirement.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply
But I want to cancel the job when compute is local, do you know a way to do this?
When I run this code when running locally, I get the following error:

"name": "HttpResponseError",
  "message": "(UserError) Compute target type 'Local' not supported by this API

Comment: Based on your info and my testing, it seems the SDK v2 does not support canceling local jobs through the API at this moment. Possible solutions will be to cancel is from job page or use any compute cluster in your job.